# Can a function in a mixin return the type of the class the mixin is applied to?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I defined my mixin :

```js
export interface EnumType<T extends string = string> {
  code: T;
  label: string;
}

export function createEnumType<T extends string = string>() {
  return class _EnumType<Code extends T = T> {
    public static readonly VALUES: _EnumType[] = [];

    constructor(
      public readonly code: Code,
      public readonly label: string,
    ) {
      _EnumType.VALUES.push(this);
    }

    public static of<C extends T>(code: C): Readonly<_EnumType<C>>;
    public static of(code: string): Readonly<_EnumType> | undefined;
    public static of(code: T | string): _EnumType | undefined {
      return this.VALUES.find(enumType => enumType.code === code);
    }

    public static getValues(): ReadonlyArray<_EnumType> {
      return this.VALUES;
    }

    public equals(enumType?: EnumType): boolean {
      return this.code === enumType?.code;
    }
  };
}
```

I use it like this :

```js
export type CountryCode = '0' | '1' | '2';

export class Country<Code extends CountryCode = CountryCode> extends createEnumType<CountryCode>()<Code> {
  public static readonly FR = new Country('0', `France`);
  public static readonly GB = new Country('1', `Great Britain`);
  public static readonly DE = new Country('2', `Germany`);
}

// ACTUAL : readonly createEnumType<CountryCode>._EnumType<CountryCode>[]
// EXPECT : readonly Country<CountryCode>[]
const a = Country.getValues(); 

// ACTUAL : Readonly<createEnumType<CountryCode>._EnumType<"0">>
// EXPECT : Readonly<Country<"0">>
const b = Country.of('0'); 

// ACTUAL : Readonly<createEnumType<CountryCode>._EnumType<CountryCode>> | undefined
// EXPECT : Readonly<Country<CountryCode>> | undefined
const c = Country.of('999');
```

My problem is that the return type of the mixin functions is not equals to the class `Country` on which I used the mixin. Types are correct but the return type let appears the mixin function `createEnumType` and the class `_EnumType` that make the type too difficult to read.

[Here the playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgUSQFcBbAFQE8xgAeMuUVJAEwGc5WYpkBzOAXg5deAPjgBvAFBw42CM2AAuOGQDc0uABtMAI2Cblnbkh7qAvpMmhIsOOiJJsMBBCSyowTKkKlK1OgwgTGxCxnyCRqIAFACUEhoeMERQbtjarOwA%20j7kVLQAwvJ4jMAs7PSCZGJSMjJgRDqaCNhCXs1wHpjMrpoUcABqAIIAMgCq%20ADKytnEudQA2gC6AnBL6hoyckhGRE7QURu19Y3tnd1IvbJFyoUKADSHdQ1NLWc9fdp6BqG8D7VwcRq-zgM18eQAdEMxpNwfVWAALKIweEIVgxdT-CyHY4vVrOFoQdA0fKBYLlERROQKG4xZQAJU8516NFBcwKIhEGKOz3anDaBPQlOuPxMtLgDK67xZOT8wDEAB84A4FOhkMBmFynicWnz8XBCULqSo4IrIqLpjK8ialSxgKqkOr4sCOsAkik4MjUZCRuMJuD7cwoqUwdQBGJg2zwVS8PxY1cFOjDlj-jjeTB%20XAeK7%20phNERgKxYvTGe9BlAoJgKNLZrLqo8XW63J7WN7oRNNXBk9ztQwAI5EXOFiOygD8ykt1DFOggEE0njcQP%20iWSTZRLejAjjw7yI6jRQ7FhkZnMlgA9Ke4ABaa83293%208Px9P58v19v9-PyzWaDwGBWwoOFwFC3DGcAAOQAAxgdaYEAIzQYqYEAExges362GkmAZHAAEoFAVYgaSpQhLhQGEYIpH4SB4ZBMR7DYJ03g1nkxIQIBVFFBSMSsQodZariuqnCWFx9AAYnSKwOgA7jhbF4RQUSQWBdxwAABqJFaOMAqmJvxaYZm8IlwAA4gAQpJwAyZRClwcpanGYxcCmdw6bIDpXKpjq6Z6oZlwACL4BZVlyUBikoSpqnGWgJCYEgFDuZIWLnnAgz5GQowjHAyi%20X0DGeExIYFCFHG8eCrKyqx7HAZxSySMl%20AABoAAr4GlWUupKRnWZV8nUbVWycHAmArNZ4JZjAOZ5gWsSqHAZ4Xql6WZcWnXMnlXjABORVVdRZVbTQABEEEHRydUXo1LVtStTIEcVVZHSdIiSAN8A6CNd3ggaSnonNZ0pWlGXDO1Eo3TQ60FWyPVkZxe3Mf41nUQqNoqmqzB-RdrX0NdUrdQjnFI8qdqo89riDS0FEfV9ACcNNgT9khAA)

**Is it possible to change `createEnumType<CountryCode>._EnumType<CountryCode>>` for `Country<CountryCode>` ?**

---

I tried something like giving the `Country` class type to the mixin function, but it not really worked.

```js
export interface EnumType<T extends string = string> {
  code: T;
  label: string;
}

export function createEnumType<T extends string = string, U extends any = any>() { // `U extends EnumType<T>` produces error `'Country' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own base expression.`
  return class _EnumType<Code extends T = T> {
    public static readonly VALUES: U[] = [];

    constructor(
      public readonly code: Code,
      public readonly label: string,
    ) {
      _EnumType.VALUES.push(this as any); // not ideal...
    }

    public static of<C extends T>(code: C): Readonly<U>;
    public static of(code: string): Readonly<U> | undefined;
    public static of(code: T | string): U | undefined {
      return this.VALUES.find(enumType => (enumType as any).code === code); // not ideal...
    }

    public static getValues(): ReadonlyArray<U> {
      return this.VALUES;
    }

    public equals(enumType?: EnumType): boolean {
      return this.code === enumType?.code;
    }
  };
}

export type CountryCode = '0' | '1' | '2';

export class Country<Code extends CountryCode = CountryCode> extends createEnumType<CountryCode, Country>()<Code> {
  public static readonly FR = new Country('0', `France`);
  public static readonly GB = new Country('1', `Great Britain`);
  public static readonly DE = new Country('2', `Germany`);
}

// ACTUAL : readonly Country<CountryCode>[]
// ==> OK
const a = Country.getValues();

// ACTUAL : Readonly<Country<CountryCode>>
// EXPECT : Readonly<Country<"0">>
const b = Country.of('0');

// ACTUAL : Readonly<Country<CountryCode>> | undefined
// => OK
const c = Country.of('999');
```

[Here the playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgUSQFcBbAFQE8xgAeMuUVJAEwGc5WYpkBzOAXg5deAPjgBvAFBw42CM2AAuOGQDc0uABtMAI2Cblnbkh7qAvpMmhIsOOiJJsMBBCSyowTKkKlK1OgwgTGxCxnyCRrwANHAAqoHB7JhIFAJwyRQiABQAlBJwAPQFcAAG8YzALOw%205FS0ZCIlcGBQ8kS47GitUKUA5ADCEA5cFL2I7B7oaJW4zHDMCB5OmqnQiCyLwMupyIgw7BAA7m46mKx41h6srC5IAHQlGh4wRFBu2NrXcAD6NX60gwUCUqIXoggaEg0MjARB0mgQ2CEXgRcA8mGYrhWcAAagBBAAysXwAGVlLEANoAXTSVPUUNkriM7Rg0Cy9OhsPhiLRGKQWLkCmUgOAUXZzU5KJ5mNS2j0BlC0XpeSkMlVPz%20dTueMJJLuMNYAAssjADQgkkkUjlVIVikgIPAEApMJo7q76RZ6TC4SjOMjERB0DR%20sCqipsgKlHB%20jllAAlTy8lY0WIidRqr1cpHOf3oLIRwzCEwxuDx9HS5NiAA%20cAcCnQyGAzDTqozPpgfrgAbz8kj9GrkSLZLg1drwHrSEbkLVMmerzcJrNWoJROJd3HzCylV8dQEYk3xFq1HSFooOTuEYE-EEEatNrgdodTpdbrVHvTEsRvuzcB4wBg2OdIhgFYXI4wTaVcSgKBMAoCsp2nWc3jgBdWCXHViWbGQ3xbD8GAARyIZ0QK3Q9gAAfmUDVqGLHQIAgTRPDcFUEL-OdkNNVCLyvQQSP%20Mjzx7TC4AsLDzEsaxoHgGAd0GYYoAoYU0l6AAGMZq16ABGNS4F6AAmXo6Qk2wPjOdhZJQeSgx7EMQnMkZFMEOz5OFMQKlDbA0W8A9-isuSFJ7GInMyXIrIUMRmNbT922-KU%20VSAAxWM0gnQ4oyGCyKCyFTehiEp4ugxxgBKK0NEirNJXAuK4AAcQAIWS4BUqCrKtNy6rPLgWruHbZBiubMqvwqssqoAEXwBqmvSkYsv0tq0BIDI%20skD0ijgXF%20jIWICTgZRYqxILfIylyqUkVarzEAB5ABpSQ5CQTh0jSIK7l-f9AOA3I6VW9bNu2sDhqTA6gpckRTuKfAAA0AAV8A2naS0qwGpssgAiZSUZEUG7oenQnuRig7i7bKSrBtaNq2-F4dLRNYKB-GQeHGsWDHBtmFJ-hLpu7H4ERRz8cJ3NegAThF3oSqAA)

Comment: This is just about the *displayed* type? If so then you probably don't want to mess with things too much. TS doesn't have *higher kinded types* as requested in [ms/TS#1213](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), nor does it allow generic `this` as in [ms/TS#6223](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6223). So there's no simple way to pass in `Country` and also let it be generic. I could imagine a quite complicated workaround, but this is unlikely to be ergonomic; might as well just override the static methods and write out your own return types. How would you like to proceed?